# google maps image not loading?

Tags: html, image

So, on the following page, the first broken image you see should be one linking to google maps. If I open up chrome's inspect tool, and right click on the src attribute to open it up in a new tab, it works fine, but it renders as a broken image on the page for some reason. any ideas?

http://test.teslaprime.com/courses/25/test_course1

Comment: The link returns HTML not and image - use the network tab on chrome developer tools and you will see the type is `text/html`

Comment: What did you do to fix it ? (just out of interest)

Comment: Y does `img` tag is referenced to html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow these instructions of google self: http://maps.google.com/help/maps/getmaps/plot-one.html

In your case you need to add the following code to your html:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=19+Chalda+Ct+San+Rafael+CA+94903&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=h&amp;ll=38.006014,-122.521711&amp;spn=0.006295,0.007989&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=19+Chalda+Ct+San+Rafael+CA+94903&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=h&amp;ll=38.006014,-122.521711&amp;spn=0.006295,0.007989&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```